# Cloud9 IDE [C9 Server Exception 2] undefined

Tags: cloud9-ide

We have installed cloud9 ide locally on ubuntu 12.04LTS 32bit server. Installation steps followed from the url http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813076
Cloud9 IDE is running and able to see home page ( localhost:3131/ )
When we try to run php or python file, on the console window it shows a message "[C9 Server Exception 2] undefined"

and also a request to  localhost:3131/debug throws "404 Not Found" 
post params are as below,
{"agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0","type":"C9 SERVER
 EXCEPTION","message":{"type":"error","message":"File does not exist: root/local/bin/node","code":2,"data"
:{"command":"Run","file":"root/local/bin/node","runner":"node","args":[""],"env":{"C9_SELECTED_FILE"
:""}}}}

How to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems that node isn't installed on the server. Can you install it using `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: nodejs and node is installed, 

root@local:~# which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
root@local:~# nodejs -v
v0.10.38

root@local:~# which node
/root/local/bin/node
root@local:~# node -v
v0.4.10

Comment: if you've installed node using `sudo apt-get install node`, you'll have to remove it. That's probably the reason you're getting this problem. Remove the node binary and install node again using `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

Installations steps in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813076 are for older version.

**Installation**

Follow these steps to install the SDK:

```
git clone git://github.com/c9/core.git c9sdk
cd c9sdk
scripts/install-sdk.sh
```

To update the SDK to the latest version run:

```
git pull origin master
scripts/install-sdk.sh
```

Please note that Cloud9 v3 currently requires Node.js 0.12 or 0.10.

**Starting Cloud9**

Start the Cloud9 as follows:

```
node server.js
```

The following options can be used:

```
--settings       Settings file to use
--help           Show command line options.
-t               Start in test mode
-k               Kill tmux server in test mode
-b               Start the bridge server - to receive commands from the cli  [default: false]
-w               Workspace directory
--port           Port
--debug          Turn debugging on
--listen         IP address of the server
--readonly       Run in read only mode
--packed         Whether to use the packed version.
--auth           Basic Auth username:password
--collab         Whether to enable collab.
--no-cache       Don't use the cached version of CSS
```

Now visit http://localhost:8181/ide.html to load Cloud9.

**Running Tests**

Run server side tests with:

```
npm run test
```

Run client side tests with:

```
npm run ctest
```

Then visit http://localhost:8181/static/test in your browser.

For more detail see: https://github.com/c9/core#installation.